# Character vector in R getting converted to a factor in a data frame

Tags: r

I was writing a function that would read a CSV file and construct a R Data Frame. This data frame has 47 columns and I was trying to split this data frame on the basis of one of the columns named "State". I am extracting the 2 and 17th column from this Data Frame and constructing a new Data Frame. The classes of these columns when I extract from the parent Data Frame are `character`. But when I create a new data frame from these columns and I see the classes of these two columns they are being reported as `factor`. My questions are these two

1. Is this expected? I am not a R veteran and I believe this should not happen. I ran some local checks by creating small data frames with a `character` and `numeric` vector and the classes were preserved when I ran the checks again
2. If this is not expected can you please help me figure out what is causing this change in the classes of the columns

Attaching the code that I have written

```
rankhospital <- function(state) {
    ## Read outcome data
    data_frame <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")

    ## Return hospital name in that state with the given rank
    ## 30-day death rate
    state_split <- split(data_frame, data_frame$State)
    state_data <- state_split[[state]]
    hospital_name <- state_data[[2]]
    outcome_state <- state_data[[17]]
    print(class(hospital_name))
    print(class(outcome_state))
    r_data_frame <- data.frame(outcome_state, hospital_name)
    r_data_frame <- subset(r_data_frame, outcome_state != "Not Available")
    print(class(r_data_frame[[1]]))
    print(class(r_data_frame[[2]]))
}
```

Attaching the output of the necessary function calls

```
> frame <- rankhospital("TX")
[1] "character"
[1] "character"
[1] "factor"
[1] "factor"
```

Comment: Try `r_data_frame <- data.frame(outcome_state, hospital_name, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`  According to ?data.frame `stringsAsFactors: logical: should character vectors be converted to
          factors?  The ‘factory-fresh’ default is ‘TRUE’, but this can
          be changed by setting ‘options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)’.`

Comment: Side note: you supply more arguments to `rankhospital` than what you define in the function definition.

Comment: @docendodiscimus I had trimmed my function before pasting it here. Forget to remove the extra parameters

Comment: @akrun Thanks. `stringsAsFactors` worked for me.

Comment: you could also use `dplyr::data_frame`, which won't ever coerce character vectors to factor.